# pandas rolling_std returning NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this

```
Out[243]: 
2016-01-04 08:35:00         NaN
2016-01-04 08:40:00         NaN
2016-01-04 08:45:00         NaN
2016-01-04 08:50:00         NaN
2016-01-04 08:55:00         NaN
2016-01-04 09:00:00    0.773413
2016-01-04 09:05:00    0.106746
...
2016-01-12 14:50:00   -0.090142
2016-01-12 14:55:00    0.285413
2016-01-12 15:00:00    0.037735
2016-01-12 15:05:00    0.292394
2016-01-12 15:10:00    0.155357
2016-01-12 15:15:00    0.807473
Freq: 5T, dtype: float64
```

I am trying to get the rolling standard deviations on this series and is returning NaN values. I am trying to compute for the above data, X:

```
pandas.rolling_std(X,10)
```

And I get...

```
....
2016-01-12 15:00:00   NaN
2016-01-12 15:05:00   NaN
2016-01-12 15:10:00   NaN
2016-01-12 15:15:00   NaN
Freq: 5T, dtype: float64
```

It is not because I have 5 NaN values in the series in the beginning. Any help will be great!

Comment: without data and request, it's difficult to help you.

Comment: How, exactly, are you invoking the method and what, exactly, is unexpected about the result?  Unless you are taking extra steps, all rolling methods will produce NaNs until the window is large enough (and certain methods that are undefined for  a datum, such as `std` and `corr`).

Comment: Yeap, `pd.rolling_std(df, window=20)` works perfectly here.

Comment: bushmanov, I am doing the above. It's been working fine until I subset-ed my data to get 5 minute intervals from 1 second interval data. I think maybe reindexing or defining the data set will do but I am not sure

Comment: adding min_periods in side the function fixed the issue. Thank you all.

Comment: Anyone has any idea why adding min_periods fixes this issue? Super strange in my opinion